# Can't log string using NLOG

Tags: c#, http, nlog

I can't log a string from an HTTP request using NLOG. Here's the code:

```
                        HttpResponseMessage res = client.PostAsync(path, content).Result;

                        if (!res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
                                File.Delete(tempFilePath);
                            String responseStr = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                            //TODO(nassim) : Remplacé ce try catch par juste un retour d'erreur dans les log

                            //ErrorReponse error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorReponse>(responseStr);
                            Logger.Debug("Taille du log : " + responseStr.Length);
                            if(responseStr.Length > 200)
                            {
                                Logger.Debug(" 1");
                                Logger.Error("Erreur d'envoi de Document a Recital : " + responseStr.Substring(0, 200));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Logger.Debug(" 2");
                                Logger.Error("Erreur d'envoi de Document a Recital : " + responseStr.Substring(0, 10));
                            }

                            if (responseStr.Contains("Invalid credentials.") || responseStr.Contains("Token is expired."))
                            {
                                refreshToken(vault, storedValues);
                                storeDocInReciTAL(env);
                            }
                            throw new Exception("Erreur d'envoi du document vers reciTAL.");
```

And here's the stacktrace:

[image]

As you can see, the line concatening with the responseStr doesn't show anywhere. At first I thought it was because the string was too long, but it's only 37 characters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest to use [structured logging](https://blog.datalust.co/nlog-4-5-structured-logging/)

Comment: Unrelated: `String responseStr = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` - Don't do that. Go async all the way. Await that call.

Comment: And if you already are _expecting_ errors, don't call Members on the string if you can't be sure it is not `null`.

Comment: `throw new Exception("Erreur d'envoi du document vers reciTAL.");` - And finally, I'd suggest to throw something _way_ more specific than a plain `Exception`. If at all.

Comment: Try to convert the string to UTF-8 encoding, and then convert that to HEX, and log that instead. I bet there is a NUL character at the beginning. Try this: `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStr)).Replace("-", "")`

Comment: Or `Convert.ToHexString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStr))` for .NET 5 and newer.

Comment: "Unrelated: String responseStr = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; - Don't do that. Go async all the way. Await that call."  -> I really don't want to do that here, I am in a short transaction and I want the code to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Using BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStr)).Replace("-", "") allowed me to print the responseSTR and then after deconverting I finally get the error "{"detail":"File type not supported."}".

Comment: I was 100% wrong when I wrote structured logging didn't worked.
With structured logging the string is properly displayed without the need to convert to HEX or repmove trailing spaces....

Comment: Maybe the string starts with BOM Unicode character. I am curious to see the original HEX string.

Comment: _"I really don't want to do that here, I am in a short transaction and I want the code to be as simple as possible."_ - That doesn't make your code simpler. It makes it more brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Using structured logging resolves the problem. I don't understand why it doesn't work with a simple concatenation.